# Calculating with time and getting a status

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I hope you can help me with this:

I´m writing a App that should show if a shop has actually open.
For this i declared for each day and each opening times different variables / NSDate-Objects like (setting the dateformatter I´ve done before):

```
    NSDate *mondayMorningOpening = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"08:00"];
    NSDate *montagMorningClosing = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12:30"];
    NSDate *mondayNoonOpening = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"15:00"];
    NSDate *montagNoonClosing = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"21:30"];
```

I´ve also set a NSDate for the actual time:

```
    NSString *tempDate1 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSDate *actualTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tempDate1];
```

Now I want to calculate if the actual time is before or after the time range for the opening times of the shop. I´ve done this:

```
    if ([actualTime earlierDate: mondayMorningClosing && [aktuelleZeit laterDate: mondayMorningOpening])
        {
         NSLog (@"The shop is open!");
        }
    else if ([actualTime earlierDate: mondayNoonClosing]&& [actualTime laterDate: mondayNoonOpening])
        {
         NSLog (@"The shop is open!");
        }
    else
        {
         NSLog (@"The shop is closed!");
        }
```

But no matter what time it is, it´s always shown "The shop is open!".

Maybe you have an idea what to do that i can show the opening status right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the meaning of earlierDate and laterDate.The methods are not "isEarlierDate" and "isLaterDate", they do not return a BOOL.These methods return a NSDate object, the earlier (or later) of the two dates.They're not nil objects, so they're always evaluated to true.

Compare the two dates taking it's time interval:

```
if ([actualTime timeIntervalSinceDate: mondayMorningClosing]<0 && [aktuelleZeit timeIntervalSinceDate: mondayMorningOpening]>0)
{
    NSLog (@"The shop is open!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I´ve just read the documentation and noticed my big mistake. But you solution works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can compare two dates, but as a result you will have a NSDate:

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");        

} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 dates you can determine if an `NSDate` is between those two like this:

```
- (BOOL)isDate:(NSDate *)date betweenFirstDate:(NSDate *)firstDate andSecondDate:(NSDate *)secondDate
{
    BOOL isEqualToFirstOrSecond = [date compare:firstDate] == NSOrderedSame || [date compare:secondDate] == NSOrderedSame;
    BOOL isBetweenFirstAndSecond = [date compare:firstDate] == NSOrderedDescending && [date compare:secondDate] == NSOrderedAscending;

    return isEqualToFirstOrSecond || isBetweenFirstAndSecond;
}
```